# Using INCLUDES with MapManager (Gisinternals)

Tags: mapserver, mapfile, map-manager

Does anybody have any experience with using Mapmanager to manage their MapServer mapfiles?

My question is specifically about using INCLUDES in mapfiles. Since having an INCLUDE in a mapfile results in error message saying "Unable to access file. Error opening included file". Which leads me to believe it is supported and I am probably just doing something wrong.

I tried using both relative and absolute path. The way I have my mapfiles is that I have them split multiple separate files MAP - contains the main map tags, LAYER - contains all the data, styles etc., CONFIG - contains any other potential information like db connection. MAP reads LAYER & CONFIG files using INCLUDE.  By themselves it works. But when I import the MAP file into mapmanager I get the error message.

Comment: did you use a relative or absolute path? where are the files in relation to the map file and does MapServer have permission to read them?

Comment: Tried using both relative and absolute path. The way I have my mapfiles is that i have them split multiple separate files MAP - contains the main map tags, LAYER - contains all the data, styles etc., CONFIG - contains any other potential information like db connection. MAP reads LAYER & CONFIG files using INCLUDE.By themselves it works. But when I import the MAP file into mapmanager i get the error message.

Comment: please use the [edit] link to update your question

Comment: Show the mapfile (or better, a short hello-world mapfile that demonstrates the problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see MapManager doesn't really handle INCLUDE files.  You can open a map file with INCLUDES if you supply full paths like below (no relative paths worked for me)

```
"C:\\apps\\MapManager\\templates\\symbols.sym"
```

**BUT**

Once opened the resultant map file used by MapManager includes all the included content.  That is you have one map file, not a map file that includes other map files.